# regex escape spaces and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting a console error:

> Cannot call method 'replace'

What I wanted to achieve is to escape all special characters and spaces.

```
text.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\/\\]/g, '\\$0');
```

So, when I have a string

> "dfgsdfgsdfg)*)(*&(*^)(*)&              dfgdg123123sdfg"

it should be read only as `"dfgsdfgsdfgdfgdg123123sdfg"`

**Note: I want to escape/ignore all non-alphanumeric characters and that includes spaces. It should only be [a-zA-Z0-9]**

P.S. newbie in regex.

Comment: Sounds like `text` is undefined

Comment: text is variable. edited

Comment: The error you posted is not because of `regex`.  the problem is with `text`.  Make sure text is a `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best approach is to match for "not alphanumeric", like so:

```
var text="dfgsdfgsdfg))(&(^)()& dfgdg123123sdfg";
alert(text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uZaxY/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
```

Or just match any non-word character which would be the best approach for this.

```
text.replace(/\W/g, '');
```

Comment: Hi mate! Still getting an error when my string is composed only of spaces or starts with special characters e.g. "             ", "`()("

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still getting an error when the string starts with "`,+/*.~!@#$%^&*() and any other non-alphanumeric characters including spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var str = "dfgsdfgsdfg))(&(^)()& dfgdg123123sdfg";
alert(str.replace(/[&/\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}^ ]/g, ""));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/43/)

Comment: Thanks! But what I only want to achieve is to only read [a-zA-Z0-9] characters only. Any other characters should be escaped

Comment: Yes..plz check the demo..the answer will be dfgsdfgsdfgdfgdg123123sdfg